# What is the standard way to represent a Python decorator in a UML design

Tags: python, uml

How do you represent in a UML design a Python Decorator for a function of a class or even as a decorator of a class. The only things I can find are *Decorator Pattern* which is significantly different then a Python Decorator.

Comment: Isn't this an implementation choice, not a design choice?

Answer (score 0):

I guess stereotypes and tagged values can help there.

Introduce the *<< decorator >>* stereotype for decorator object, and the *<< decorates >>* for the dependency relationship, I can suggest the *<< decorates >>*  can have the "*target*" attribute to hold target name. Additionally you can introduce the *<< decorated >>* stereotype for methods and fields to keep it clear what methods and fields are decorated. *<< decorated >>* stereotype can have the "*decoratedBy*" attribute to hold names of the applied decorators.

Let me illustrate what I mean.

Decorator -> Class Relationship

[image: One for "decorator -> class" relation]

Decorator -> Class Method Relationship

[image]

Hope it will help.